# Delete the rows with all value zero and keep one specific column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, I want to delete the rows with all zero. However, the first column is the id and I want to keep that column. I check with

```
df  = df[(df.T != 0).any()]
```

however, it delete all the column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['id'] = [ 'a',  'b', 5, 'd' ]
df['b'] = [ 0, 9, 0, 2]
df['c'] = [ 0, 2, 0, 2]
df['d'] = [ 0, 7, 0, 5]
```

Here is the new DataFrame which I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a boolean mask that returns True if none of the non-"id" column values are 0 for each row, False otherwise:

```
out = df[df.drop(columns='id').ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
  id  b  c  d
1  b  9  2  7
3  d  2  2  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sum` all 0 if the result less than 3 then we keep it

```
df[df.eq(0).sum(1)<3]
Out[438]: 
  id  b  c  d
1  b  9  2  7
3  d  2  2  5
```